# SublimeREPL and rails console

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sublimetext2, sublimerepl

Is there any method to run rails console via [SublimeREPL](https://github.com/wuub/SublimeREPL) (or another plugin) in Sublime Text?

Answer (score 0):

You can try the SublimeREPL plugin. https://github.com/wuub/SublimeREPL